# cassandra new node Unknown keyspace

Tags: cassandra

I have a 6 node cluster running 1.1.5. I added a new node running the same version. The new node joined the cluster without any issues. But we are seeing the below error messages in the system.log

```
ERROR 10:15:53,455 Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:320,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown keyspace
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try running a repair on the new node?  Maybe the system tables didn't fully sync up when it joined the cluster.

Comment: Yes tried running it but didn't workout.